# Is it dangerous including the link to the pMA login page?

Tags: database, security, hyperlink

On the private section/CMS of my website I'd like to include a link to the php MyAdmin login page of the MySQL database I use for the website. Is it dangerous/inadvisable?

E.g.

```
<a href="http://server.something.com/pMA">Link to database</a>
```

Comment: What would be a reason for having this?

Comment: I can reach the login page faster.... ok I could use favourites on the browser, but if I have to verify something on the db not from my computer... then is convenient!

Comment: `/pMA` would be where I'd try to find phpMyAdmin anyway.

Comment: and the address of the server?

Comment: I would not provide more attack surface than absolutely necessary. This means no public administrative interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned about "private section" of CMS, so I assume, that the entire operation requires two separate logins -- one to CMS and second (after clicking a link) to phpMyAdmin itself.

Contrary to most of the comments, I don't find this too risky. I assume, that if any certain attacker gains access to your system, in the meaning, that it bypasses (in any manner) both login stages, then finding out exact address of your phpMyAdmin installation is a matter of seconds. Giving him or her direct link doesn't help much and doesn't lower your security level. Sill -- assuming, that both your CMS and PMA login processes are as secure as possible.

Of course, that using own browser bookmarks (especially now, when nearly every browser offers you any kind of bookmarks' synchronization) is far better and maybe little bit more secure.  But this is not the case in my opinion, as you asked specifically about revealing your PMA link on CMS site.

I'm not even sure, if *not* giving that link, in this particular scenario, wouldn't qualify as *security through obscurity*. But, that is just a private thoughts.

BTW: In this particular case, phpMyAdmin is just an example. You could ask the same question about any DB management system, tool or application or even general -- if revealing a direct link to manage page or system is a good idea. For this, I suppose this question fits much better to [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).